# how to stop appending the table every time you have change something on a dropdown.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqplot

I am running in to an tricky problem with my jquery ajax call. 
I have following event which is triggering the ajax call to the respective url and will draw the chart.

after drawing the chart I wanted to display the respective data for that chart in a table so i have appended a table as following

```
$('#managers').on("change", function(){
var drawBubbleChart = bubbleChart.getData();
bubbleChart.drawchart(drawBubbleChart);
$.each(drawBubbleChart, function(index, value) {
    $('#bubbleChart3').append('<tr style =background: black; color: "white"><td>'+value[3]+'</td><td>'+value[0].toFixed(2)+'</td><td>'+value[1].toFixed(2)+'</td><td>'+value[2].toFixed(2)+'</td></tr>');
  });
```

it works fine like this:
[image]

for the first time I change the drop down but every time I have changed the drop down it appends the data and chart on top of this which is not supposed to happen. 
if anybody have the idea how do i stop this? would be much more appreciated

Comment: You could add a boolean variable say dataAdded. as a global variable. Set it to true on first call then check this variable every time the function is called and don't run the each statemnt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you replace the rows, rather than append them?

```
$('#managers').on("change", function() {
    var drawBubbleChart = bubbleChart.getData();
    bubbleChart.drawchart(drawBubbleChart);
    var rows = '';
    $.each(drawBubbleChart, function(index, value) {
        rows + ='<tr style =background: black; color: "white"> <td>'+value[3]+'</td><td>'+value[0].toFixed(2)+'</td><td>'+value[1].toFixed(2)+'</td><td>'+value[2].toFixed(2)+'</td></tr>';
    $('#bubbleChart3').html(rows);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

To keep the header rows, you could place them inside a `<thead>` element and place an empty `<tbody>` element after that. Then you can change the last line of code to:

```
$('#bubbleChart3').children('tbody').html(rows);
```

Comment: Thanks John, this works in some extend but how do i keep the headings of the tables? because headings are from the HTML.

Comment: @DC! - I had a feeling that would be an issue. I updated my answer.